# ImageButton Background Not Changing

Tags: android, image, button, background

I have an imageButton and and I would like to change the background of it in code but I cannot figure out why this will not work...

```
public class Game extends Activity{

    ImageButton btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
}
```

Comment: what is the result that you are getting?

Comment: The image would not change at all.  But I just got it to work using this code: "btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);"  But now if I put this code in an onClick event, the image will not change.  Any ideas?

Comment: what is `btn1` in the `onClick` method??? Is it the same as `R.id.btn1`?? You could use the view that is passed as parameter to set the background instead of btn1

Comment: Yes it is the same as R.id.btn1

Comment: Try the second part of my previous comment!

Comment: Ok, .setImageResource works for both instances.  Eclipse was just being stupid and mixing up my buttons so I had to re-do my layout.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use

```
btn1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
```

to change the background

**setBackgroundResource** indcates src of an image where as **src** and **background** has lot of difference